# css height does not grow up

Tags: html, css, height

I have a web page that is divided into header, page and footer.

The problem is that I made the page `height :auto;`.
But it does not work and I need the page to automatically grow up.

This is what I have in the CSS:

```
/* Page */

#page-wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#page {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 1120px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 50px 40px;
    color: #8F8F8F;
    min-height:700px;
    height:auto;

}
```

And HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="banner">
  <div class="img-border">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
      <div id="header">      
        <div id="logo">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="page">
      <div id="wide-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ohh ok i will edit my question

Comment: Please post *all* relevant code and preferably a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I don't understand what's the question and what's the intended behavior.

Comment: html, body { height: 100%; }

Comment: Do you have floating elements?

Answer (score 2):

It is very unclear what it is that you want.

In your first line you say you want a footer, but your HTML and CSS don't show any footers.

If you want a footer which sticks to the bottom of the page, have a look at the [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the height in there at all... a div will grow or shrink with the amount of content inside of it. Try removing height: auto; completely.

If though you mean that you want to make the content section 100% of the page height even when there isn't enough content, this should help [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Comment: Just updated the answer... I'm guessing you want it to fill the screen is the reason for the auto height? Again, a div should always stretch to the height of its content. So we may need a bit more than "it did not work"

Comment: i mean it pass out the div page and the content of the page  go to the footer

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the footer of your page at the bottom and the div imbetween to take up the remaining space (it's a little difficult to determine from your wording)?

If this is you what you want, I'd suggest looking at this blog post:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

HTML summary:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS summary:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

Comment: that is not what it happen with me    sir i have a comment box so when the comment become having 10 or more lines its content go down to the footer section